# how to add two bits into a hex

Tags: c++, c, hex, bit

I have two bytes and I am setting different bits in order to get different combinations.
E.g, byte 1 bit 7 and byte 2 bit 1,bit 2 makes a combination device ready.
Now, I have created mask

```
#define C1_device_ready   (0x80 | 0x100 | 0x200)
```

Then I read the data and try to compare.
for 1 byte I can do (data[0] & mask == mask).
But how can I compute it for C1_device_ready mask where there are two bytes, data[0]
and data[1].
Is it easily possible or should I do masking only in single byte.
::added::data is unsigned char data[2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `data` is an array of `unsigned char`, you could test

```
if ((data[0] & mask) == (mask & 0xFF) && (data[1] & mask) == ((mask >> 8) & 0xFF))
```

or combine the two `data[i]` and check

```
if (((data[0] | (data[1] << 8)) & mask) == mask)
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Could you please explain the bit shifting (<< 8).

Comment: `data[0] | (data[1] << 8)` combines the two bytes from the `data` array into one `int`, having `data[0]` in the least significant byte, and `data[1]` in the second-least-significant byte per the shift. Since the bit operations `<<` and `|` automatically make integer promotion happen, there's no need to insert a cast to a larger type manually.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
if (((data[0] | (data[1] << 8)) & mask) == mask) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
((data[0] | (data[1]<<8)) & mask) == mask
```

should work. Might need to cast things as `unsigned int`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if ((*(short *)data) & C1_device_ready)
```